# How do you dynamically change a DNN page title from a DNN module?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, title, page-title

How do you dynamically set a DNN page title from a DNN module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `Page.Title` to a custom string.
Note that you must do this in `Page_PreRender`

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Title = "Your new page name goes here";
}
```

Comment: Apparently not many DNN custom module programmers wish to do this, else this would be a very popular answer.  Thank you thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

In MVC DNN Module put to your _Layout page

```
@{
     ((Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler).Title = ViewBag.Title;
 }
```